# How to compare two columns with other two columns for duplicates in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, comparison

I need to compare columns `C` and `D` with `A` and `B` and only if exist same combination of two cells in one row. Hope the image below will explain the situation better.

[image: Image of example data]

Comment: Do the matches have to be on the same row or can they be on any row in the two columns?

Comment: In the same row

Answer (score 2):

In E1 you can put

```
=IF(AND(C1=A1,D1=B1),"exist","")
```

and drag it down.

Comment: what if order is not same and some values missing ,so this wont apply

Answer (score 0):

See below (I put in the row 1 header line, after I took the screenshot, but you get the idea)

1) move Column C & D over to D & E

2) in C1 put in `=A1 & B1`

3)  Same for now Column D & E

so in F1 put in `=D1 & E1`

4) next in G1 put in `=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(F1,$C$1:$C$100,1,FALSE)),"","exists")`

Then drag G1 down to the bottom of your columns. Change `$C$1:$C$100` to your range before you change

You can then also hide Column C & F as you don't need them visible

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it's good idea, but I don't get correct results, I'll try to work on this because of not so simple input data

Answer (score 0):

```
VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE(D2,E2),CONCATENATE(A2:A8,B2:B8),1,0)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).